How to create V2 and V3 signed Apk in Android Studio
How to create V2 and V3 signed Apk in Android Studio , required steps to create v2 and v3 signed apk
Previously it showing the option that do you want to create apk with v1 or v2 while signing the apk but now it is not showing that option.
